# Typescript filter adult and child

Tags: angular, typescript

The filter is not working properly. I want to filter the adults with their child numbers and include them in the records. How can I fix the code?

.html

```
<input id="adult" type="number" [(ngModel)]="adult" (ngModelChange)="changeNumberOfAdults()" />
<input id="child" type="number" max="3" min="0" [(ngModel)]="childCount" [(ngModel)]="chd" (ngModelChange)="changeNumberOfChilds()" />
```

.ts

```
changeNumberOfAdults() {
    const filtered = this.hotels.filter(x => x.numberOfAd == this.adult);
    this.dsHotels.data = filtered;
}

changeNumberOfChilds() {
    const filtered = this.hotels.filter(x => x.numberOfChd == this.chd);
    this.dsHotels.data = filtered; }
```

Comment: you want to show the hotels with both the conditions met?

Comment: Yes. I cannot assign a size sample image because the filter is not working properly. The hotel name, check in and checkout dates work correctly. The number of adults and children does not work correctly.

Comment: Please do not include images to indicate what you are trying to achieve. Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information,  see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I will consider your suggestion. I will consider your suggestion. I want to filter by the number of adults and children entered on the search screen.

Comment: I think you can't use 2 [(ngModel)] in the input field.

Comment: I used one but the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a single function, e.g:

```
filterHotels() {
    const filtered = this.hotels.filter(x => x.numberOfAd == this.adult && x.numberOfChd == this.chd);
    this.dsHotels.data = filtered;
}
```

Then:

```
<input id="adult" type="number" [(ngModel)]="adult" (ngModelChange)="filterHotels()" />
<input id="child" type="number" max="3" min="0" [(ngModel)]="chd" (ngModelChange)="filterHotels()" />
```

And yes you should only have one ngModel on an input so remove

```
[(ngModel)]="childCount"
```

See [StackBlitz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpvsjm).

As the values are stored in the adult and chd variables in your .ts file, the values are always available to the function so a single function can filter on both values no matter which model change triggers it.

Note, you should be able to add any of the other filter variables to this function too and just call it from all your inputs.

Comment: I applied this but the same problem comes from all the records.

Comment: Did you look at the StackBlitz demo link? It works there so should give you enough details if you have a look through it.

Comment: You could make your own StackBlitz that recreates the problem you are having which will make it much easier to look into.

Comment: The issue may also be that data in the main array is being overwritten by changes in other inputs. Stackblitz showing a simple recreation of the problem would help. You can base it on the on I did.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your functions should consider both the filters.

```
changeNumberOfAdults() {
    const filtered = this.hotels.filter(x => {return this.chd == undefined ? x.numberOfAd == this.adult : x.numberOfAd == this.adult && x.numberOfChd == this.chd } );
    this.dsHotels.data = filtered;
}

changeNumberOfChilds() {
    const filtered = this.hotels.filter(x => {return this.adult == undefined ? x.numberOfChd == this.chd : x.numberOfAd == this.adult && x.numberOfChd == this.chd } );
    this.dsHotels.data = filtered; }
```

Also, this is a very good case to write a custom filter Pipe in angular, and can avoid use of `onModelChange`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work right. It brings all the records.  13.08.2020 and 14.08.2020. https://imgyukle.com/i/nOviIR

Comment: I might have flipped the conditions wrong, how about now?

Comment: unfortunately the same problem.